# How to get the cost from database of a certain product by inputting a serial number?

Tags: laravel

[UI FOR INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F1eL.png)

I'm trying to develop a simple sales system that will get the cost of a product if the user inputs a serial number and it will automatically display the total.

**Form Invoice blade**

**Script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    var max_fields      = 120;
                    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
                    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");
                    var remove_button   = $(".remove_field_button");
                    var total = 0;


                    $(add_button).click(function(e){
                      e.preventDefault();
                      var total_fields = wrapper[0].childNodes.length;

                      if(total_fields < max_fields){
                        $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="serial" class="form-control" />');
                      }
                      $(document).ready(function(e){
                       $("input").change(function(){
                        var total = 0;
                        $("input[name=serial").each(function(){
                          total += parseInt($(this).val());
                        })
                        $("input[name=total]").val(total);
                      });

                     });

                    });

                    $(remove_button).click(function(e){
                      e.preventDefault();
                      var total_fields = wrapper[0].childNodes.length;
                      if(total_fields>1){
                        wrapper[0].childNodes[total_fields-1].remove();
                        $(document).ready(function(e){

                          var total = 0;
                          $("input[name=serial").each(function(){
                            total -= parseInt($(this).val());
                          })
                          $("input[name=total]").val(-total);
                        });


                      }


                    });
                  </script>
```

Comment: There's nothing here that sends a request to your backend...

Comment: But how will you do it if this is the problem sir?

Comment: I cant find some good reference about this.

Comment: There are plenty of resources online that teaches you how to send and receive data. You need `json` to do this. Maybe checking out `text-box autocomplete` tutorials will help you.

Comment: Removed blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand you are trying to achieve, is query the database asynchronously.

For that you should have some kind of JavaScript code, that sends requests to an API in your Laravel application and receives appropriate data.

I can see you are using jQuery, so the simplest approach would be to use jQuery.ajax().

Fire the code below when your user inputs ID:

```
var globalCost = null;

$.ajax({
    url: "your/api/url",
    method: "post",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
       id: YOUR_ID,
    }
})
.done(function (response) {
    globalCost = response.cost
});
```

Than, in YourModelController create a function like  this:

```
public function getCost(Request $request){
    $id = $request->input('id');
    return YourModel::where('id', $id)->pluck('cost');
}
```

The above returns instance of a given ID.

You need one more thing, which is route to your API function. This can be done either in `api.php` or `web.php` inside `/routes/` folder.
For example:

```
Route::post('your/api/url', 'YourModelController@getCost');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make an SQL query to find the cost of product from the database with the condition of that specific product (product id or serial number).

Comment: But how should I do that if I'm using real-time when adding the cost?

Comment: You are using a MySQL database with core PHP / PHP framework?

Comment: Below should work.

Model::where('serial_number', 123)->get();

Comment: And how will I used it to my blade? After I do that to my controller?

Comment: By sending that variable to the blade.

return view('welcome')->with($data);